# Personal Cloud Storage from backup files

Tags: 16.04

Do Ubuntu give personal cloud storage for saving files and installed software. If not available, then what is other cloud storage available for Linux Ubuntu for saving files and configured/installed software.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ubuntu does not give personal cloud storage anymore: that once came together with UbuntuOne, but the service has been shut down since.

About other cloud storage services I cannot improve over what you can find by googling around a bit.

Bye.

Comment: @David Foerster. I guess it's a misunderstanding: I only meant that if I had to give a list of available cloud storage services, I wouldn't be able to do better than googling around a bit.

Comment: @David Foerster. I edited the answer trying to make it clearer.